# Gridview inside a Gridview

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have attached the image exactly what i need to implement.I want to know how to set images inside a particular grid in a gridview and also it has to hold maximum five images.And how the images inside a grid gets resized according to the number of images in it??

Answer (score 0):

@ user3433015, [i think you will be clear by following this.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8NoHxfIu0MQ&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6hYgvtkaWvwAVvOFB7fkLa) Follow from 92 to 98 tutorials.

Comment: @ user3433015, Please vote or reply if problem solved.

Comment: My Question is..i want to insert maximum of five images inside a partcular grid in a gridview.The above mentioned link gives an idea about normal gridview..

Comment: For a particulate grid view use intent and start another Activity which has max of 5 grids.